# Angularjs invoke class restricted directive using ng-class

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom

I have a directive defined like this

```
.directive('activet', [function(){
  var link = function(scope, element, attrs){
    console.log('in acivet directive');
  };

  return {
    link: link,
    restrict: 'C'
  };  
}])
```

activet will be invoked when an element has the class 'activet'

```
<div ng-class="{'activet':currentImage===image}" class="lb-single-thumb" ng-repeat="image in allImages" ng-click="changeCurrentImage(image, $index)">
  <!-- div contents here -->
</div>
```

My logic being that when ng-class directive adds 'activet' to the div, my directive will get invoked.

But my directive never gets invoked.  I went through the docs but couldn't find any reason for this.  Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Where are you calling the directive? It doesn't look like you are

Comment: My logic being that when ng-class directive adds 'activet' to the div, my directive will get invoked.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, I could've sworn when you use that syntax in something like `ng-class`, the `activet` **class** will be applied to the element **if** `currentImage===image`...that's it. I don't think that's how you apply a directive. I may be wrong

Comment: duplication http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18598810/how-do-i-apply-an-angularjs-directive-based-on-a-class-set-by-ng-class

Comment: @FedorSkrynnikov  Thanks.  Missed that question. This cleared my doubts.  I am not deleting my question as it might benefit someone like me. I guess someone from the community will mark this question as duplicate now.