# How do I dynamically add an AngularJS directive to an element conditionally?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, web, angularjs-directive

So I can't really get this to work, I've got the following code

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="plunker" >
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script>document.write("<base href=\"" + document.location + "\" />");</script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.2/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  {{vt.t}} 
  <div my-directive="{{vt.t}}"></div>
  {{vt.f}}
  <div my-directive="{{vt.f}}"></div>

  <hr />

  {{vt.t}} 
  <div ng-class="{'my-directive': vt.t}"></div>
  {{vt.f}}
  <div ng-class="{'my-directive': vt.f}"></div>

  <hr />

  <div class="my-directive"></div>
  <div class="nodirectiveclass"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.vt = { t: true, f: false };
});

app.directive('myDirective', function($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'AC',
    template: '<div>Directive on</div>',
    replace: true
  };
});
```

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/7cJKhIuNqnsk1CkczjoE?p=preview

As you see the classes doesn't trigger the directive when added dynamically but works fine in my last "static" example. I also tried setting the directive attribute to true or false but that didn't seem to help.

Comment: This is because ng-class set the class after the compilation process, everything is explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18599528/1062711

Comment: Workaround would depend on what directive does. Might be able to use `ng-if` or `ng-switch` or may have to put more logic in directive depending on use

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use model variable in your directive. Then you can access what ever the value you want easily.

Refer this Answer: 
[AngularJS - Create a directive that uses ng-model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14115701/angularjs-create-a-directive-that-uses-ng-model)