# How to load class restricted Angular directive by binding name?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Scenario: I have two class restricted directive definitions. I want to load them into their own tab panels by binding their directive name to a div class. When I set the class name explicitly in a div, the directives will render just fine. However, whenever I try to set the class name via binding, it doesn't render.

Layout Markup:

...

```
<div class="tab-content">
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="{{component.id}}" ng-repeat="component in components">
    <h3>{{component.name}}</h3>
    <hr />
    <div class="{{content.directive}}"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also tried using

```
ng-class="{{content.directive}}"
```

to no avail.

Layout Javascript:

```
(function () {
    var demoLayoutCtrl = function ($scope) {
        $scope.components = [
            {
                name: "File Upload",
                directive: "file-demo",
                id: 1
            },
            {
                name: "Line Chart",
                directive: "line-chart-demo",
                id: 2
            }
        ];
    };

    demoLayoutCtrl.$inject = ['$scope'];

    var demoLayout = function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'EA',
            replace: true,
            templateUrl: '/Content/templates/demo/demo-layout.html',
            controller: demoLayoutCtrl
        };
    };

    angularApp.directive('demoLayout', demoLayout);
}());
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Edit: This is not a duplicate of the suggested post, because I am not asking how to apply a directive conditionally based on a class value. Rather, I was asking about directly data binding the name of a class restricted directive into an element and have it render the directive.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I apply an AngularJS directive based on a class set by ng-class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18598810/how-do-i-apply-an-angularjs-directive-based-on-a-class-set-by-ng-class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [`ngSwitch`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch):

```
<div ng-switch="content.directive">
    <div class="file-demo" ng-switch-when="file-demo"></div>
    <div class="line-chart-demo" ng-switch-when="line-chart-demo"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This worked perfect, thanks for such a fast response! Would you happen to know why my initial approach wouldn't work? I have a feeling it has something to do with the scope digest and the timing of the bindings. Still fairly new to Angular, so some of the inner workings get a little confusing.

Comment: Not sure, did you try modifying `content.directive` inside a `$timeout` callback function? If that doesn't work, you can rule out scope digest.

Comment: Nah, I'm not doing any promise callbacks or AJAX calls, so that shouldn't be the case. After further reading, it seems that the compilation process occurs before the DOM is finished rendering. So the class is essentially set in a sequence beyond when the directive templates would be replaced in the first place. With this in mind, your answer is perfectly fine and saves a lot of headache. Thanks again!