# Angular - Dynamic Directive Call (Class)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive that I can successfuly call as

```
<div class="testDirective"></div>
```

but I doesn't work when

```
$scope.variable = 'testDirective'
```

I try all these examples

```
<div ng-class="variable"></div>
<div ng-class="{{variable}}"></div>
<div class="variable"></div>
<div class="{{variable}}"></div>
```

Nothing works...

Thanks

Comment: I believe this is similar 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18598810/how-do-i-apply-an-angularjs-directive-based-on-a-class-set-by-ng-class

Answer (score 0):

your variable is not in scope

```
scope.variable = 'testDirective'
```

and in html

```
<div class="{{variable}}"></div>
```

Comment: this was not an actual line of code. my variable is on scope...
the problem is that doesn't load then directive in that way... If you try it, you will see

Comment: scope.variable = 'testDirective' defined in directive?

Comment: I have a directive and i can call this with this code
<div class="testDirective"></div>

Comment: the problem is when the class name is variable and not a string

Comment: you don't need the directive, the only think you need to know is that it is work.

Comment: I think this is not possible.