# ng-class does not trigger custom directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-directive

Ive created an `AngularJS` directive which will be triggered on all elements with the *classname* `.collapse`.

But when I add this *class* using Angular's `ng-class`  directive, the custom `collapse` directive is not triggered.

**Demonstration of my problem**

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.welcome = "model";
    
    $scope.isTrue = function() {
      return true;
    }
});

app.directive("directive", function($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'C',
    scope: {
      model: '@'
    },
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      elem.css("background-color", "blue");
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.directive {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <p>Simple Angular app</p>
  <div class="directive">Make my background color blue using the directive</div>
  <div ng-class="isTrue() ? 'directive' : ''">Make my background color blue using the directive</div>
</div>
```

How can I make the `directive` also trigger on *classes* which are added using `ng-class`?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this has been [answered already here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18598810/how-do-i-apply-an-angularjs-directive-based-on-a-class-set-by-ng-class).

Basically, ng-class is setting the class too late - after the DOM load.. Applying a condition to the directive could be done within the directive itself to avoid this problem. There are examples within that link of using the attribute rather than class for the directive, and then doing the check within the directive. Hope that helps. Below is an example that shows this:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.6.0/underscore.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.welcome = "model";

        $scope.isTrue = function() {
          return true;
        }
    });

    app.directive("directive", function($compile) {
      return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: {
                'condition': '='
            },
            link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
            scope.$watch('condition', function(condition){
                if(condition){
                    elem.css("background-color", "blue");
                }
            });
        }
      }
    });
</script>

<style>
.directive {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <p>Simple Angular app</p>
      <div class="directive" directive condition="true">Make my background color blue using the directive</div>
      <div class="directive" directive condition="false">DO NOT make the background blue because the condition is false</div>
      <div directive condition="isTrue();">Make my background color blue using a function for the the directive</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18417533)

Comment: Thank you for the input - I've added additional details and a working code sample for reference.